# 2012 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Physics's [second moderator election](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Qmechanic] 
[image: Manishearth]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://physics.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election/2).

Comment: Congrats to both!

Comment: Shouldn't this be `featured`? Congratulations to the winners!

Comment: Congrats to the winners!

Comment: congratulations to both

Comment: Excellent choices, congrats to both!

Comment: The Stackexchange mechanism for community self moderation seems to work good. The right candidates came out. Congratulations!

Answer (score 13):

Am I allowed to post data from the results here?  I thought I might save other people some time.

The following is a total count of the number of votes cast for 1st, 2nd, and 3rd choice for each candidate.

```
                    1   2   3   all
Chris Gerig         9   15  25  49
Qmechanic           134 38  11  183
Manishearth         23  79  28  130
user1504            5   11  19  35
Larian LeQuella     10  20  35  65
Crazy Buddy         4   8   25  37
MKB                 5   4   10  19
Total votes         190 175 153 518
```

Of course this misses the cross-correlations, which would be important for runoffs, but your method wouldn't matter much for this election.

The average voter cast a vote for 2.726 candidates.  Total of 190 people voted, reflected in the first choice column because you can't vote without casting a first choice.

Comment: Sure, the results as published by SE are public knowledge.

Answer (score 11):

Indeed, congratulations to the two new moderators!  I had a suspicion that this is exactly how it would turn out.  Makes all the drama seem rather silly in the end.  ;)  I think the community made the perfectly correct choices in this, and I am very happy with the final result.

Comment: Some men just want to watch the world burn.  ;)

Comment: @UnbanRonMaimon: Three independent users marked it as offensive/not constructive with a flag. Three flags cause a comment to be auto deleted :/ I also removed the offensive part of this comment, please don't use such words here..

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations to the new community mods and *best of luck*!

Answer (score 6):

Good result.  Well done folks!